The problem with arabic language in xhtml2pdf django
I’m using xthml2pdf to generate invoice with arabic language. I searched a lot to solve the problem and followed all the steps, but I don't know why it doesn't work.
Utils code:
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, encoding='UTF-8')
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')

View code:
pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html'), context)
if pdf:
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    filename = "invoice-%s.pdf" % invoice_number
    content = "inline; filename= %s" % filename
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content
    return response

And finally the HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
  @font-face{font-family:samim; src: url('/assets/fonts/Shabnam-FD.ttf') }
  body{
      background: #fff;
      font-family: samim !important;
      direction: rtl !important;
  }
   </style>
   </head>
  <body>
   <div>
  <pdf:language name="arabic"/>
  <p>سلام</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>

But this is what is generated in the end


Are you sure this is not just the font for which there are no Arabic characters available? (just guessing)

@willeM_VanOnsem xhtml2pdf could not find OP’s font files.

When using xhtml2pdf with Django, allow URL references to be resolved using Django’s STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL settings. That way in any environment, your code will work because Django does the heavy lifting.
xhtml2pdf allows users to specify a link_callback parameter to point to a function that converts relative URLs to absolute system paths. See one example here. [xhtml2pdf-docs]
Using this function (url_converter for example), your code should be:
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    #•••Rest of your code•••
    result = BytesIO()
    result.seek(0)
    status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=result, link_callback=url_converter)
    if not status.err:
        result.seek(0)
        return FileResponse(result, content_type='application/pdf')
Remember to collectstatic files in so that Django can locate your files correctly.

After trying a lot of diffrent things to generating PDF.
I tried xhtmltopdf and also wkhtmltopdf etc.
later deploying was very difficult for me ,was getting errors after errors.
Then I switched to selenium 4.0 which has easy pdf option no with all the settings.
I suggest you to move to selenium here easily.
But the only concern is cloud resource . You can evaluate that for your further benefit.
